# Djangi : django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'email' into field

Tags: javascript, django, e-commerce

**I Got errors like that, please help me.
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'email' into field. Choices are: auth_token, created_at, id, is_verified, nama, order, pengiriman, user, user_id

view.py

```js
def processOrder(request):
    id_transaksi = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
    data = json.loads(request.body)

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer        = request.user.profile
        order, created  = Order.objects.get_or_create(user=customer, selesai=False)
        
    else:
        customer, order = gusetOrder(request, data)
        
    total = float(data['form']['total'])
    order.id_transaksi = id_transaksi

    if total == order.get_cart_total:
            order.selesai = True
    order.save()

    if order.shipping == True:
           Pengiriman.objects.create(
               user=customer,
               order=order,
               alamat=data['shipping']['address'],
               kota =data['shipping']['city'],
               provinsi=data['shipping']['state'],
               kode=data['shipping']['zipcode'],
           )
    return JsonResponse('Payment complete', safe=False)
```

checkout.html

```js
function submitFormData(){
                console.log('Payment button clicked')

                var userFormData = {
                    'name':null,
                    'email':null,
                    'total':total,
                }

                var shippingInfo = {
                    'address':null,
                    'city':null,
                    'state':null,
                    'zipcode':null,
                }

                if (shipping != 'False'){
                    shippingInfo.address = form.address.value
                    shippingInfo.city = form.city.value
                    shippingInfo.state = form.state.value
                    shippingInfo.zipcode = form.zipcode.value
                }

                if (userau == 'False'){
                    userFormData.name = form.name.value
                    userFormData.email = form.email.value
                }

                console.log('Shipping Info:', shippingInfo)
                console.log('User Info:', userFormData)
                
                var url = "/process_Order"
                fetch(url, {
                    method:'POST',
                    headers:{
                        'Content-Type':'applicaiton/json',
                        'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
                    }, 
                    body:JSON.stringify({'form':userFormData, 'shipping':shippingInfo}),
                    
                })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log('Success:', data);
                    alert('Transaction completed');  

                    cart = {}
                    document.cookie ='cart=' + JSON.stringify(cart) + ";domain=;path=/"

                    window.location.href = "{% url 'store' %}"

                })
            }
```

base.html

```js
function getToken(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    const csrftoken = getToken('csrftoken');
```

trouble picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5cnc.png)

models.py

```js
class Profile(models.Model):
    user        = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    nama        = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    auth_token  = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at  = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Product(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    harga       = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=3)
    digital     = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    jumlah      = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image       = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url
    
class Order(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order_data  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    selesai     = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    id_transaksi = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True) 

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

utils.py

```js
def gusetOrder(request, data):
    print("User is not logged in")

    print('COOKIES:', request.COOKIES)
    name = data['form']['name']
    email = data['form']['email']

    cookieData = cookieCart(request)
    items = cookieData['items']

    customer, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(
        email=email,
        is_verified=True,
        auth_token="null",
    )
    customer.name = name
    customer.save()

    order = Order.objects.create(
        user=customer,
        selesai=False,
    )

    for item in items:
        product = Product.objects.get(id=item['product']['id'])

        orderItem = OrderItem.objects.create(
            product=product,
            order=order,
            quantity=item['quantity']
        )

    return customer, order
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email is not there in your profile model that's why you are getting error.
If you want to create an object filter user object and by that, you can create or get customer

```
customer, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(
            email=email,  # getting error here.
            is_verified=True,
            auth_token="null",
        )


class Profile(models.Model):
    user        = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    nama        = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    auth_token  = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at  = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Solution

```
user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()

customer, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(
        user=user,
        is_verified=True,
        auth_token="null",
    )
```

Comment: I have Already add in models.py:    email       = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True). getting new error: AttributeError at /admin/accounts/profile/

Comment: Please share the proper error message.

Comment: if I open admin see order and pengiriman get error like that"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'username'", and open Profil get erorr" 'str' object has no attribute 'username'"

Comment: Share error image.